# Solve $x''(t)+3x'(t)+2x(t)=3exp(t)$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I need to solve this 2nd order ODE and I will denote it by $\ast$

\begin{align}
x''(t)+3x'(t)+2x(t)=3\exp(t)
\end{align}

My try:
I start by solving the homogenous 2nd order ODE.

The characteristic polynomial is

$\lambda^2+3\lambda+2=(\lambda+1)(\lambda+2)=0$. So the solution are $\lambda=-1$ and $\lambda=-2$. Hence, the solutions to the homogenous 2nd order ODE is
\begin{align*}
x(t)=A\exp(-t)+B\exp(-2t) \ \ \ t,A,B \in \mathbb{R}
\end{align*}
Now, I look at the inhomogeneous 2nd order ODE. I guess that the solutions is $u^{\ast}=C\exp(qt)$. I differentiate $u^{\ast}$ with respect $t$ and plug it into $\ast$ and get
\begin{align*}
C\exp(qt)\big(q^2+3q+2\big)=3\exp(t)
\end{align*}

For $q^2+3q+2\neq0$ then the solution to $\ast$ is
\begin{align*}
x(t)=A\exp(-t)+B\exp(-2t)+\frac{3\exp(t)}{q^2+3q+2}
\end{align*}

Is this correct?

Comment: For the particular solution, guess $x_p(t) = c e^t$ (undetermined coefficients), substitute back into ODE and solve for constant. Your homogeneous part is correct. Your approach is making it harder, but you should be able to deduce that $q = 1$, sub that back in and get the correct result.

Comment: Amzoti is right.  See if your textbook discusses the method of undetermined coefficients (or similar name).  This is a method to help you make an educated "guess" for the particular solution.

Comment: It makes sense. Thank you for the help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your guess is a good one, and will get you what you need. Bear in mind that the equation $$C(q^2+3q+2)e^{qt}=3e^t$$ must hold for **all** $t,$ so dividing both sides by the never-zero function $3e^{qt}$ shows us that $$\frac13C(q^2+3q+2)=e^{(1-q)t}\tag{$\star$}$$ for all $t.$ Taking the derivative gives us $$0=(1-q)e^{(1-q)t},$$ so since $e^{(1-q)t}$ is never zero, then $1-q=0,$ so $q=1.$ So, by $(\star),$ we have $2C=1,$ so $$u^*=\frac12e^t,$$ and so your general solution is of the form $$x(t)=Ae^{-t}+Be^{-2t}+\frac12e^t.$$